# BranchPythonOperator not running with past skipped state task

Tags: python, airflow

This is how my airflow dag looks like

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVuWn.jpg):[Airflow dag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVuWn.jpg)

There is a branch task which checks for a condition and then either :

Runs Task B directly, skipping task A or

Runs task A and then runs task B

When task A is skipped, in the next(future) run of the dag, branch task never runs(execution stops at main task) although default trigger rule is 'none_failed' and no task is failed in the dag only skipped.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'wait_for_downstream': True, 
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
    'trigger_rule': 'none_failed'
}

dag = DAG(
        dag_id='main_task',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval='0 2 * * *',
        start_date=datetime(2021,6,2),
        max_active_runs=8,
        )
def check_condition():
    if(conditionA == conditionB):
        return ['task_A','task_B']
    else :
        return 'task_B'

branch_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branching',
    python_callable=check_condition,
    dag=dag,
    depends_on_past=False,
)
```

Using Airflow 1.10.12.
Could someone guide me why branch task never runs after task A is skipped in the past run.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is happens isn't related to trigger rules.
It happens because `default_args` in DAG constructor contains `wait_for_downstream=True`
so when you do:

```
branch_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branching',
    python_callable=check_condition,
    dag=dag,
    depends_on_past=False,
)
```

What actually happens is that `depends_on_past` is set to `True` by the [constructor](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/7529546939250266ccf404c2eea98b298365ef46/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L559-L560) of `BaseOpeartor`.
Since `wait_for_downstream=True` will cause a task instance to also wait for **all** task instances immediately downstream of the previous task instance to succeed this causes the `BranchPythonOperator` to not start running. This is a problem as branch operator usually have direct downstream tasks in Skip status.

You can fix it by:

```
branch_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branching',
    python_callable=check_condition,
    dag=dag,
    depends_on_past=False,
    wait_for_downstream=False
)
```

I'd like to note that this is an issue only in Airlfow<2.0.0 because `wait_for_downstream` consider only Success status as accepted ([1.10 operator description](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d3b066931191b82880d216af103517ea941c74ba/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L132)).

For Airflow > 2.0.0 this issue won't happen as the behavior was changed in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/7735)  by making `wait_for_downstream` consider both Successful and Skipped tasks as accepted statuses ([2.0 operator description](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e0a41971a1c57221a5e03c70fc670a4c09f19d8a/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L271)).